# How can I convert all columns in my database to case insensitive

Tags: postgresql

I have seen that it is possible to convert all **tables** to case insensitive names using the following commands in psql:

```
\o /tmp/go_to_lower
select 'ALTER TABLE '||'"'||tablename||'"'||' RENAME TO ' ||
lower(tablename)||';' from pg_tables where schemaname = 'public';
psql -U username database < /tmp/go_to_lower
```

I have been unable to unearth a command to convert all **columns** to case insensitive in the same way. How can this be achieved?

EDIT: Apparently the above code only converts table names to lower case. I am aware that this code ALTER TABLE "YourTableName" RENAME TO YourTableName; will convert to case insensitive for a table name. Is there a way to do a similar function on mass for column names?

Comment: In case it makes a difference to you, that's not case insensitive; that's converting them all to lower case.

Comment: It also makes them case insensitive doesnt it as there are no quotes around the column names when they are renamed.

Comment: Do you want to make the column **names** case insensitive or the column **values** when comparing the data?

Comment: The actual column names themselves. I am having trouble with accessing them via an alias.

Comment: No, postgres just converts the names to lowercase unless you quote it during table create/alter statements and queries.

Comment: Further to my point above; if you don't quote the names on create or rename, then PG will convert them to lower case.  It will likewise convert names in queries to lower case, so it's effectively the same thing - never quote your table or column names and everything will be lower cased so should work.  If you're having problems with aliases, perhaps update the question to indicate the problems that you're having so that we can help.

Comment: The alias thing is really a seperate issue that I have now resolved. The main issue here remains that I would like to convert all column names to case insensitive. When I used FME to create my tables previously it used quoted names in the create scripts and so I had to manually rename all the tables to be case insensitive using this script. ALTER TABLE "YourTableName" RENAME TO YourTableName; This worked perfectly. I now want to know if there is a way to do a similar function to this on mass for every column name to avoid lengthy repetition.

Comment: Then either vyegorov's or my solution below should work for you.  Have you tried them?

Comment: For a better method of doing this, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/49521068/124486

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Along the same lines as the original, then, you should be able to do the following.  This renames all columns that are not already in lower case, by extracting them from the information_schema, generating SQL for the changes, storing it to a file then executing the SQL again.

```
\t on
select 'ALTER TABLE '||'"'||table_name||'"'||' RENAME COLUMN '||'"'||column_name||'"'||' TO ' || lower(column_name)||';' 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema = 'public' and lower(column_name) != column_name
\g /tmp/go_to_lower
\i /tmp/go_to_lower
```

Comment: Isn't this just for one column?

Comment: No, it's for all of them.  I've updated the layout to be clearer and changed the query to be more clever (so that it doesn't bother to try to rename columns already in lower case).

Comment: If you need to do it for sequences :
`select 'ALTER SEQUENCE '||'"'||sequence_name||'"'||' RENAME TO ' || lower(sequence_name)||';' from information_schema.sequences 
where sequence_schema = 'public' and lower(sequence_name) != sequence_name;`

Comment: If you need to do it for constraints: `select 'ALTER TABLE '||'"'||table_name||'" RENAME CONSTRAINT ' || '"'||constraint_name||'" TO ' || lower(constraint_name)||';' from information_schema.table_constraints 
where table_schema = 'public' and lower(constraint_name) != constraint_name;`

Comment: It would be nice if we could rename existing camelCase and PascalCase tables/columns to snake_case.

Answer (score 22):

By default, all you identifiers are case insensitive, and internally PostgreSQL stores them in lowercase. In case you need to have:

- case sensitive
- non-ASCII characters
- special characters

within your identifiers, you should use double quotes (`"`) around your identifiers.

Please, check [this bit](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) of the PostgreSQL documentation.

**EDIT:** After your clarification, you can use:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '||quote_ident(t.relname)||' RENAME TO '||t.relname||';'
  FROM pg_class t, pg_namespace s
 WHERE s.oid = t.relnamespace AND s.nspname = 'public'
   AND t.relkind='r' AND t.relname != lower(t.relname)
 ORDER BY 1;
```

and for columns:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '||quote_ident(t.relname)||
       ' RENAME COLUMN '||quote_ident(a.attname)||
       ' TO '||a.attname||';'
  FROM pg_class t, pg_namespace s, pg_attribute a
 WHERE s.oid = t.relnamespace AND s.nspname = 'public'
   AND t.relkind='r'
   AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND NOT a.attisdropped AND a.attnum > 0
   AND a.attname != lower(a.attname)
 ORDER BY 1;
```

Then copy-paste the output into your client.

If you're using `psql`, you can use `\t` to enable rows-only mode, `\o <full_file_path>` to save output into the temporary file and, finally, `\i <full_file_path>` to execute actual statements.

Comment: This is a good explanation of the reasons behind the problem, but not really a solution to the OP's question.

Comment: @ElYobo The OP does not state what the problem is. He hints in a comment that he has problems with using alias. So it seems he is trying a solution for a problem that is not the one he is experiencing.

Comment: Perhaps we're reading a different question, or it has been changed by edits?  I can see the following above - "I have been unable to unearth a command to convert all columns to case insensitive in the same way. How can this be achieved?".

Comment: Identifier refers to both, table and column names. And all the reset, like view, sequence, schema, etc. names.

Comment: @ElYobo In that quote he states he has a problem implementing a solution but does not say what the original problem is. Now in the last comment he finally says he used a certain tool which quoted the identifiers and that clarifies the underlying problem.

Comment: Nice and handy.  Thanks.   However, in the 2nd statement you should leave out "AND t.relname != lower(t.relname)" because it omits tables which are already all-lowercase.

Comment: @PhilHord Why would you want to modify tables that are already lowercase?

Comment: @mts the 2nd statement is about renaming columns to lowercase, not tables. But it originally filtered out lower-cased tables as well as columns.  Looks like it was fixed since then.

Answer (score 1):

I created a SQL query on Database Administrators that does just this.

1. Converts all identifiers to lower case
2. Converts spaces `' '` to `'_'`
3. Does this for all schema, table, and column names

For more information see,

- *[How do I adopt the PostgreSQL naming convention in legacy database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/202446/2639)*

Answer (score 0):

```
do language plpgsql $$
declare
    r record;
begin
    for r in
        select relname, attname
        from pg_attribute a
        inner join pg_class c on a.attrelid = c.oid
        inner join pg_namespace n on c.relnamespace = n.oid
        where 
            n.nspname = 'public'
            and
            attname != lower(attname)
            and
            not attisdropped
    loop
        execute format('
            alter table %1$I rename column %2$I to %3$s
        ', r.relname, r.attname, lower(r.attname));
    end loop;
end;
$$;
```

Issue a `begin;` before trying this. Check if it is correct. Only then issue a `commit;`. If you are using a namespace then substitute it in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add a step by step guide using PgAdmin for beginners like myself and those who are not used to command line tools like psql:

Execute the following query in PgAdmin:

```sql
SELECT  'ALTER TABLE ' || quote_ident(c.table_schema) || '.'
  || quote_ident(c.table_name) || ' RENAME "' || c.column_name || '" TO ' || quote_ident(lower(c.column_name)) || ';' As ddlsql
  FROM information_schema.columns As c
  WHERE c.table_schema NOT IN('information_schema', 'pg_catalog') 
      AND c.column_name <> lower(c.column_name) 
  ORDER BY c.table_schema, c.table_name, c.column_name;
```

*Source: https://www.postgresonline.com/article_pfriendly/141.html. Note that you do not need to change anything here.

Now export the result to a textfile.

[image]

Open the .csv file with Excel, Notepad or any texteditor of your choice. Copy all lines except the first one ("ddlsql") and past them into a new query in PgAdmin. Make sure to remove doubled text quotations. Run it and done.