# SQL - HINT to reference a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am very beginner at SQL, so I am sorry if this question is primitive. 
I just started following the tutorial of http://www.w3schools.com, so downloaded the "Northwind" database to try working on it, and using the pgAdmin 3 console to access the DB. 
I just tried simple command to choose one column of the table, but it gives the same following message with any column from any table

```
LINE 1: select City from Customers;
                        ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "customers.City".
```

I would like to ask is there any thing wrong in my command? and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: w3school has been hacked? (I get all kinds of reli-nonsense)

Comment: @wildplasser I think the proper URL is http://www.w3schools.com

Comment: @wildplasser sorry it was my mistyping. I edited that link as Martin said.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

When you imported this "Northwind" database column names were imported in CamelCase - your import must've added double quotes to column identifiers to `create table` queries.

This is rather unfortunate, as this would cause that you'd have to quote them also in all queries, like:

```
select "City" from customers;
```

To remain sane I'd suggest you to [rename all columns to lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10086532/15862). This way it wouldn't matter what case you use, as Postgres converts all unquoted identifiers to lower case automatically. Then any of this would work:

```
select city from customers;
select City from Customers;
SELECT CITY FROM CUSTOMERS;
```

Comment: Thank you @Tometzky ! It worked after renaming all columns. However, I would ask you if you have any reference about importing a database in a way that I would keep all the names as they were originally.

Answer (score 8):

My working query ended up looking like:

```
select descr from activity where "activity"."scheduleId"='6sdCkROlyMo';
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your query. It looks like your tutorial wants you to follow the practice of always prepending the table name to columns you reference. In reality, this is only required when it would otherwise cause an ambiguity (e.g. if you are referencing two tables, both of which have a City column).

Comment: This looks like a postgres feature not a tutorial. http://pgeoghegan.blogspot.co.uk/2015/11/suggesting-corrected-column.html I would guess something to do with case sensitivity as `customers` vs `Customers` leaps out but am not familiar enough with Postgres to be sure.