# Hibernate and postgresql after migration from Oracle

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have problem with right set configuration of spring-boot, jpa and postgresql database.

All my queries hibernate launch without quotes and in lowercase. Postgresql dont accept this, and return error.

My application.yml file:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/xxx
        username: xxx
        password: xxx
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
    jpa:
        show-sql: true
        naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
            default-schema: madmax
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
    hadoop:
      config:
        fs.defaultFS: hdfs://192.168.56.104:54310/
```

Example of enitity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RecommendationItem")
public class RecommendationItem {
```

And preview of hibernate query log:

```
Hibernate: select recommenda0_.id as id1_2_ [...] from recommendation_item recommenda0_ where recommenda0_.user_id=?
```

And error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "recommendation_item" does not exist
```

It is possible to config this architecture without renaming all annotation in entities?

Comment: dunno what you are asking, log says `relation "recommendation_item" does not exist`, you shouldn't have an entity `RecommendationItem`, it is only a relation, which can be described with annotations.. if you don't want to use annotation, what do you have in mind?

Comment: Postgresql should not care about case on tables as default. Are you sure you are connection to the right database, and that you have a table called recommendation_item in the database?

Comment: When I take this hibernate query and run in postgresql i get this same error. All is correct when I add quotes to query and uppercase table name: (select recommenda0_."ID" 
from "RECOMMENDATION_ITEM" recommenda0_ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two possibilities:

1. The configuration parameter `search_path` does not include the schema that contains `recommendation_item`, so it cannot be found.

   **Solution:** add the schema to `search_path`.
2. You kept the table name in upper case when you migrated the table from Oracle, so it is called `RECOMMENDATION_ITEM`.

   The problem here is that while Oracle folds unquoted names to upper case, as the SQL standard directs, while PostgreSQL folds them to lower case.

   **There are two solutions:**

   - Rename the tables to lower case names.
     I think that this is the better solution.
   - Always use quoted parameters, like `"RECOMMENDATION_ITEM"`.

Comment: Thanks! It is a second option. I use scripts from http://stackoverflow.com/a/10087286/2847298 and everything is ok now :-)